# Error: The new file /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.cli does not exist!

Tags: php, php7

After updating my system I received this error:

```
Setting up php7.0-cli (7.0.5-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Error: The new file /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.cli does not exist!
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-fpm:
php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-cli; however:
Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cgi:
php7.0-cgi depends on php7.0-cli; however:
Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cgi (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
php7.0 depends on php7.0-fpm | libapache2-mod-php7.0 | php7.0-cgi; however:

Package php7.0-fpm is not configured yet.
Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not installed.
Package php7.0-cgi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Please explain. There seems to be a lot of missing files and configuration error. Please follow the release notes or installation instructions in terms of whatever you are trying to do?

Comment: This is the same error I get trying to install php 7.0.5 from [`ppa:ondrej/php`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with a broken build in the PHP 7.0.5 packages in Ondrej's PPA.

According to his [bug report](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/315#issuecomment-204030883), the new build has just completed.

Try again (you probably have to `apt-get update`) and it should work.

---

If `apt-get update` doesn't help, you might also need to manually remove the old package cache manually:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 libapache2-mod-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Does not really work for me :(

Comment: @kwoxer this question is due to a specific bug that occurred 3.5 months ago, so it is unlikely related to your problem. You should post a new question.

Comment: Mhh I just removed both Packages. Purged. Then reinstalled. Now works.

Answer (score 2):

after 2 hours of testing, this worked for me:

1. remove (purge) apache and all php packages:

   ```
   apt-get purge php*
   apt-get purge apache2
   ```
2. install these packages:

   ```
   apt-get install apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [bug report](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/315#issuecomment-204030883) `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` works well!