# Unable to configure dpkg

Tags: dpkg

I was trying to install php and somehow my dpkg got screwed up. General googling did not help here. Can anyone explain me what is that I have to do here ? Its been quite a while and I have not been able to come up with a solution.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
 php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-fpm:
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-cli; however:
  Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-fpm depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0
 php7.0-cli
 php7.0-fpm
 php7.0-json
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Yes I have but it gave same error. (http://dpaste.com/2RSQ81B)

Comment: Try [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/803436/308164). If not, check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/752397/error-the-new-file-usr-lib-php-7-0-php-ini-production-cli-does-not-exist)

Comment: Was not helpful. Still having the same error.

Comment: Remove php and do `sudo apt update` and see if it does through. Perhaps an inclusion of the steps or method used to install `php` would also help.